# Projection between graphs extends to a covering space

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

This is exercise 1.A.10 on page 87 of Hatcher's book [*Algebraic topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

> Let $X$ be the wedge sum of $n$ circles, with its natural graph structure,
>   and let $\tilde X \to X$ be a covering space with $Y \subset \tilde X$ a finite connected subgraph.
>
> Show there is a finite graph $Z ⊃ Y$ having the same vertices as $Y$, such that
>   the projection $Y→X$ extends to a covering space $Z→X$.

**Question:**

How can we obtain graph $Z$ by adding edges from the given finite graph $Y$?

This turned out to be Marshall Hall's Theorem in Stallings' article  [*Topology of finite graphs*](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~nbrady/teaching/s11-5863/stallings.pdf). But I need more explanations.

For example, an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/621155/557551) says for the case where $X=S^1 \vee S^1$, $\tilde X$ is the universal covering space, and $Y=B(1,n)$, i.e. the ball of radius $n$ and centered at $1$ in the graph $\tilde X$, the covering space $Z \to X$ extending projection $Y \to X$ is just $B(1,n)$ with additional edges between vertices of the sphere $S(1,n)$.

Could someone give an explanation for this?

---

**Edit 1:**

This can be used to [prove](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21050/133793) the [residual finiteness](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group) of finitely generated free group, which states:

> If $F$ is a finitely generated free group and $x \in F$ is not the identity element, then there's normal subgroup $H \subset F$ of finite index s.t. $x \not \in F$, hence $x$ has nontrivial image in a finite quotient group of $F$.

**Edit 2:**

This can be used to [prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809653) this:

> Let $F$ be a finitely generated free group and $H$ be a finitely generated subgroup of $F$. Let $x∈F−H$. Then there is a finite index subgroup $K$ of $F$ such that $H⊆K$ and $x∉K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm just a graph theorist who doesn't see why the topologists are making a big deal out of all this...

But I'm pretty sure that a covering space of $X$ is equivalent to a (possibly infinite) directed multigraph whose edges are $n$-colored in such a way that every vertex is incident to exactly one incoming and one outgoing edge of each color.

The finite connected subgraph $Y$ is therefore a directed multigraph whose edges are $n$-colored in the same way - but with "exactly one" replaced by "at most one".

The claim in Hatcher's exercise is just that we can patch the "at most" problem and get back to *exactly* one incoming and outgoing edge of each color, by adding only edges and not vertices.

To see this, let's deal with one color at a time. There are three kinds of problem vertices for the $i^{\text{th}}$ color:

1. Vertices with an incoming edge but not an outgoing edge of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color.
2. Vertices with an outgoing edge but not an incoming edge of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color.
3. Vertices with neither of those.

Because the total number of incoming edges of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color is the same as the total number of outgoing edges, and everything is finite, there is an equal number of vertices of type 1 and type 2. So we can patch those vertices by pairing them up, and adding an edge of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color from each type 1 vertex to the paired type 2 vertex.

To patch type 3 vertices, just add a loop of the $i^{\text{th}}$ color at those vertices.